# How do I use CkEditor with email?

Tags: 7, rules, wysiwyg

I'm trying to do the following to allow the CkEditor to be used with a rule-based email.

```php
function mymodule_form_rules_ui_edit_element_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['parameter']['message']['settings']['message']['#type'] = 'text_format';
  $form['parameter']['message']['settings']['message']['#format'] = 'full_html';
}
```

I receive the following warning.

> Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in check_plain()

The email I receive contains *Array* as body. It seems like I am hitting the issue described on [Add a method for easily enabling CKEditor on a specific textarea](http://drupal.org/node/1031160).

Is there a way to convert the output of CkEditor into a string?

Comment: Drupal 7, out of the box, does not allow you to send HTML emails. Don't forget to fix it by installing Mime Mail module.

Comment: Thanks but I have a bunch of email modules installed and working properly, and that's not my issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I figured it out myself how to resolve it.

You should use a *text_formatted* field, not *text_format*, otherwise the Rules module cannot correctly render the field. You need to use a different `hook_rules_action_info_alter()` to change the field type, as in the following code.

```php
function mymodule_rules_action_info_alter(&$actions) {
  $actions['mimemail']['parameter']['body']['type'] = 'text_formatted';
  $actions['mimemail_to_users_of_role']['parameter']['body']['type'] = 'text_formatted';
}
```